# Maximum timeout for process

Tags: centos, timeout, slurm

I have a script which I think can take few days to finish. Basically it submits slurm jobs when queue isn't full and in the process it can wait a while.

The script results in incomplete results, making me think that there is a maximum execution time. Is this kind of default timeout really exists? If yes, how can I reset to unlimited time?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit which parts are slurm jobs and which parts are your script and which parts take a long time to run and which parts you think aren't completing?

Comment: Actually slurm jobs has nothing with the problem here. The script is a regular bash script. The length of execution is no problem as long as it is finished. The script is supposed to make folders for each case. Since some of the folders are missing I deduce that the script stopped working. I guess the problem is logging out. I see in other posts that people use nohup to make scripts run even after logout.

Answer (score 0):

Unix systems in general don't have a maximum execution time for programs, but shared compute clusters *often* enforce a maximum execution time on jobs running via a batch system, such as SLURM or LFS etc.

Contact the administrators of the compute farm you are using. They will be able to help you debug this.  Your SLURM jobs may well be running out of time if there's a default maximum execution time set on the cluster for jobs submitted to it.

It also happen sometimes that a timeout is set on interactive sessions on shared login nodes.  Again, the system's administrators would be able to inform you about this.

Comment: But it is not the SLURM job which stops running the script but the server itself. I will ask the admin anyway.

Comment: @Shibli Yes, there is usually no timeout on a Unix process, but this may be configured by an administrator.  They could enforce a logout after a certain time of inactivity for example.  See with your sysadmins to make sure that you you are away of the restrictions on this system.